# Ways to Memorize "Discreet" and "Discrete"

Tags: etymology, word-usage, orthography, mnemonic, historical-change

I have a question about *discreet* and *discrete*. People tend to get these two words mixed up, and I would like to help them memorize these two words.

*Discrete*: unconnected; separate
*Discreet*: judicially reserved; prudent

(Definitions from Word Smart...)

Comment: Those are not really third-grade words. And they occur in different contexts. Are you concerned about the spelling, or the meanings?

Comment: Again, I meant to say 6th graders. I am more concerned about the way to memorize them, but I would appreciate it if you could explain all three so that I am accurate in what I tell my 6th grade students.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it may be asked on ELL or meta.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### *discrete*

The best way to remember the difference is that *concr**ete*** and *discr**ete*** end the same: *-ete*.  Something which is *discr**ete*** is pinned down, precise: *concr**ete***.

### *discreet*

The other one is that clandestine spies and surreptitious lovers should always *m**eet*** in a *discr**eet*** location instead of on the *str**eet***, choosing instead somewhere far from prying eyes and ears, perhaps even behind a *sh**eet***.

Answer (score 9):

The two *e*'s in *discrete* are separated (by a *t*) just like the difference between discrete categories

Comment: The discrete *e*s is how I remember it myself.

Answer (score 3):

"You could think of the adjacent *e*’s in *discreet* discreetly sharing a secret: they couldn’t do this with a *t* in the way." ([Source.](http://stancarey.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/keeping-discreet-and-discrete-discreetly-discrete/))

Answer (score 1):

This is understandably difficult, as the [etymologies](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=discreet) trace back to the same ancestor.

I didn't really comprehend the difference until I took calculus, where I first realized that discrete values had nothing to do with being discreet.

Perhaps you could explain that *discrete* is used in math and science, and have your students recognize it as a sight word. In contrast, *discreet* is used in relationships, and they will probably use it more often in writing.

Another contrast would be the opposites:

- discrete / continuous
- discreet / indiscreet (or foolish or inconsiderate)

Comment: There's also the problem that _discretion_ is the noun form of _discreet_, likewise the negatives _indiscretion, indiscreet_. The noun form of _discrete_ is _discreteness_, and the negative is _non-discrete_.

Comment: I had learned in calculus that the negative of *discrete* is *continuous*. For example, a stock price takes on discrete values (say a value of $123.00 or $123.01, and does not venture between). But while a person's weight may be 60 kg or 61 kg, his weight may take on any continuous value between those two points, and does not jump discretely among values. To confuse the poor 6th graders even more, I had one prof use the verb "discretize," that is, to force continuous numbers to discrete values. I'm hoping that no one would attempt forcing *discreet* into a verb.

Comment: Well, in certain branches of mathematics -- especially ones dealing with real numbers and limits -- that's the case. But in others _non-discrete_ simply means that the property of _discreteness_, however it may be defined, is absent.

Answer (score 1):

I always remember it by looking at the e's (the part of the word where they differ). In *discrete*, the e's are separated by the t so the e's are discrete.

Answer (score 0):

Discrete: unconnected; separate

Crete

Comment: More specifically - if you want the word that means 'separate', pick the one with the same ending!